# Drawing a simple text on a View

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have been developing the application for drawing and I have some problems: the mean for drawing by a finger has been done already, but now I need to make anything that allow user to write a common text label on a `View`. So, please, look at my code:

```
public class PainterView extends View implements DrawingListener {

    private Painter painter;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint bitmapPaint;
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;

    public PainterView(Context context, Painter painter) {

        super(context);
        this.painter=painter;
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        PainterView.this.painter.touchStart(x, y);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        PainterView.this.painter.touchMove(x, y);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        PainterView.this.painter.touchUp();
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }

        });
        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("event", "click");
            }

        });
        this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.e("event", "long");
                return true;
            }

        });  
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (bitmap!=null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        } 
    }

    public void onPictureUpdate(Bitmap bitmap, Paint bitmapPaint, Path path, Paint paint) {

        this.bitmap=bitmap;
        this.bitmapPaint=bitmapPaint;
        this.path=path;
        this.paint=paint;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setPainter(Painter painter) {
        this.painter=painter;
    }
}
```

It's code for drawing; the process of drawing is in `Painter` class. So, now I need to allow user to write a simple text. I thought that I can do it using long clicks - user do a long click, keypad is opened, and user can input a text. But it doesn't work! I don't see any strings in my Log.

Please, tell me advice about my problem or some idea how I can realize what I need.

Comment: [Try this one](http://www.2shared.com/file/QMsoV6OR/WriteOnScreen.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `OnTouchListener` is consuming the touch event when you `return true`. Try `return super.onTouch(v, event)`.

Comment: OnTouchListener is interface, there is no super method